# how to write a linux shell variable to a file's given line?

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to Realize the function shown as the below FAKE code: to compute the net down rate and update the net log.
May somebody show me the right code?  Thanks.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #check_net.sh

    net_link_error_total=33
    net_link_ok_total=55
    save_link_rate()
    {
        sed -i  '1 cnet_link_error_total=$net_link_error_total' yy.log
        sed -i  '2 cnet_link_ok_total=$net_link_ok_total' yy.log

        net_link_ok_rate=net_link_ok_total/(net_link_ok_total+net_link_error_total) * 100%
        sed -e "3c  net_link_ok_rate= /$net_link_ok_rate" yy.log    
    }

    save_link_rate
```

After I executed `sed -i  '2 cnet_link_ok_total=$net_link_ok_total' yy.log`

- The yy.log is `net_link_error_total=$net_link_error_total`
- BUT I want it to be `net_link_error_total=33`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first two sed commands, variables are not expanded within single quotes.

Your last command applied to third line will works as intended but it's a good practice to restrict expansion to only variables, and not to enclose whole sed command within double quotes. Moreover I would add a space after each sed  `c` commands for readability:

```
sed -i  '1c net_link_error_total='"$net_link_error_total"'' yy.log
sed -i  '2c net_link_ok_total='"$net_link_ok_total"'' yy.log

sed -e '3c net_link_ok_rate= /'"$net_link_ok_rate"'' yy.log
```

Also your rate calculation is wrong. You can use `bc` for this:

```
net_link_ok_rate=$( echo "scale=2; $net_link_ok_total/($net_link_ok_total+$net_link_error_total) * 100" | bc)
```

Finally, note that with your last sed command the file will not be edited in place, as the `-i` flag is missing.

Comment: The line `net_link_ok_rate=net_link_ok_total/(net_link_ok_total+net_link_error_total) * 100%
` is not supposed to work right? It is not done in the arithmetic context, isn't it? or am I missing something here?

Comment: @BeyondOcean Which first two lines? If you mean  the first two sed commands, they are not. That's why you don't see expected replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes, because single quotes limit substitution of variables. In your case, what you want is:

```
sed -i "1 cnet_link_error_total=$net_link_error_total" yy.log
sed -i "2 cnet_link_ok_total=$net_link_ok_total" yy.log
```

If you want to do a float division in `bash`, you should use a tool such as `bc`. In your case, for example:

```
ok_rate=$(echo "scale=2; $ok_total/$((ok_total+error_total))" | bc)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU awk with the in-place module (versions 4.1.0 and above), then:

```
awk -i inplace -v error=$net_link_error_total -v ok=$net_link_ok_total \
    'NR == 1 {$0 = "net_link_error_total=" error}
     NR == 2 {$0 = "net_link_ok_total=" ok}
     NR == 3 {$0 = "net_link_ok_rate=" (ok + error)*100/ok}
     1' yy.log
```

`$0` is the current line, and `NR` the line number, so I set each matching line to the required string.

If the field names are already in the file in those lines, you can simplify it further, but setting the field instead of the whole line:

```
awk -i inplace -F= -v error=$net_link_error_total -v ok=$net_link_ok_total \
    'NR == 1 {$2 = error}
     NR == 2 {$2 = ok}
     NR == 3 {$2 = (ok + error)*100/ok}
     1' yy.log
```